# Cascading Dropdown in mvc4 with ajax is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In web.config:

```
<add name="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-SLJTE7M\TAHMINA;Initial Catalog=UniversityDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"></add>`
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult TeacherCoursAssign()
{
    ViewBag.Departments = GetDepartments();
    return View();
}    
public List<Department> GetDepartments()
{
    List<Department> departments = departmentManager.GetAllDepartments();
    return departments;
}

public JsonResult GetTeachersByDepartmentId(int deptId)
{
    var teachers = GetTeacher();
    var teacherList = teachers.Where(a => a.DepartmentId == deptId).ToList();
    return Json(teacherList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In view page:

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm">`
    ....
    <label for="departmentId">Select Department</label>
    <select name="departmentId" id="departmentId">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        @foreach (var department in ViewBag.Departments)
        {
            <option value="@department.DeptId">@department.DeptName</option>
        }
    </select>

    <label for="teacherId"></label>
    <select name="teacherId" id="teacherId"></select>

    <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>


@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#departmentId").change(function() {
                $("#myForm").submit(function() {
                    return false;
                });
                var deptId = $("#departmentId").val();
               $("#teacherId").empty();
               var json = { departmentId: deptId };
                alart(deptId);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetTeachersByDepartmentId", "TeacherCourseAssign")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            alert(key);
                            $("#teacherId").append('<option value=' + value.TeacherId + '>' + value.TeacherName + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

After loading my view page for this specific controller the cascading dropdown is not working. It's loading the department name but not that teacher name for that specific department. I couldn't find my mistake.

Comment: I would recommend you to use console.debug()  instead alert() all over your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter in your `GetTeachersByDepartmentId()` method is named `deptId` and your not sending a value for `deptId` (only one for `departmentId`), so its vakue is `0` and your query would return no results for `.Where(a => a.DepartmentId == 0)`. Change ajax call to

```
var json = { deptId : deptId }; // change
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetTeachersByDepartmentId", "TeacherCourseAssign")',
    data: json, // change
    success: function(data) {
        ....
    }
});
```

Note also to remove the `contentType` option. You should also remove `$("#myForm").submit(function() { return false; });` from your script.

There are also other issues with your implementation, particularly if you need to return the view and I recommend you review the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym).

Comment: Thank U.. this ws a big hlp for me :D